# Two or More Functions in App Script for Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms, google-apps

I have three triggers created in **App Script** for a single google sheet.

This Google Sheet receive responses from three different Google Forms.

I set a trigger that is executed when a person fill one of this forms and then, according to the form, fill a google sheet tab and execute the function.

The problem that I have now is when a person fill the form all three triggers are executed.

Code is something like this:

```
`function blablabla() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('blablablaTab');
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var lastline = data.reverse()[0];

  var data1 = lastline[2];
  var data2 = lastline[1];
  var data3 = lastline[3];
  var data4 = lastline[6];`
```

Can you guys help me please?

I tried to modify some google sheet attributes but still doesn't work. When a form is filled the three triggers are executed.

Comment: Welcome. Can we just clarify this... you have three sheets in a spreadsheet, each sheet is linked to a different Google Form. You have three functions that are each relate to a specific sheet/form. You have three `onFormSubmit` triggers, one for each of the three functions. Is that correct?

Comment: You only need one onFormSubmit trigger.  You can tell which linked sheet it is writing to with e.range.getSheet().  Then you can provide an object to call the appropriate function for each trigger.

Answer (score 0):

"*The problem that I have now is when a person fill the form all three triggers are executed.*"

You have a spreadsheet with three sheets, each sheet linked to a Google Form. You have three `onFormSubmit` triggers which means that you must have three separate functions - one for each sheet/form. Your problem is that when a form submission is received, all three functions are triggered.

You should have only **one** `onFormSubmit` trigger; this trigger should be linked to only **one** function.

There are several strategies that you could adopt to create a single function. The most obvious is to consolidate the three functions into a single function, as shown below. This may not be the most efficient, however the design of the function is not intended to be part of this answer.

```
function getResponse(e) {
  // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) // DEBUG

  // test for response from form #1
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() === "Form Responses 1"){
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: received a form 1 response")
    // do stuff
    // insert code from form 1 script     
  }

  // test for response from form #2
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() === "Form Responses 2"){
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: received a form 2 response")
    // do stuff
    // insert code from form 2 script 
  }

  // test for response from form #3
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() === "Form Responses 3"){
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: received a form 3 response")
    // do stuff
    // insert code from form 3 script 
  }
}
```